# Window Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, winjs

I am developing window phone 8.1 WinJS application. I set the style 'width:450px;border:1px solid' to body to check it fit the screen. Whey I test it on Nokia Lumia 635 it does not show right side border only Window phone emulator 1080p 6 inch shows it fully. Any body knows where is the problem

Comment: This sound more like an HTML problem to me. Why are you working with absolute numbers instead of percent?

Answer (score 0):

Effective pixel resolution for 4.5 inch device for windows phone 8.1 RT is 384x640. You should read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465349.aspx) for screen sizes in windows 8.1 RT apps